# Why at high circle division, the cone not complete itself?

Tags: webgl

I created in webgl a javascript file that needs to draw a cone. If I choose a low circle division, it work perfectly, and all the lines are displayed. But at high one, high from 255, it breaks. It seems not all of the vertices are linked. I can not understand why the difference.

```
case 'cone':{
  var CONE_DIV = 255;
  var angolo = 360 / CONE_DIV;
  var altezza = 1.0;

  // Coordinates
  var vertices = [];
  vertices.push(0.0); //v0t X
  vertices.push(0.0); //v0t Y
  vertices.push(0.0); //v0t Z
  vertices.push(0.0); //v0 X
  vertices.push(altezza); //v0 Y
  vertices.push(0.0); //v0 Z
  for (var i = 0; i < CONE_DIV; i++) {
    var ai = i * 2 * Math.PI / CONE_DIV;
    var si = Math.sin(ai);
    var ci = Math.cos(ai);

    vertices.push(ci); //coordinate X
    vertices.push(0.0); //coordinate Y
    vertices.push(si); //coordinate Z
  }

  // Colors
  var colors = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < CONE_DIV; k++) {
    for (var t = 0; t < 2; t++) {
      colors.push(a);
      colors.push(b);
      colors.push(c);
    }
  }

  // Indices of the vertices
  var indices = [];
  //index high vertex
  for (var j = 1; j <= CONE_DIV; j++) {
    indices.push(1);
    indices.push(j+1);
    var l = j + 2; //last vertex base - return to first
    if (l == CONE_DIV + 2) {
      indices.push(2);
    } else {
      indices.push(l);
    }
  }
  //index base
  for (var j = 1; j <= CONE_DIV; j++) {
    indices.push(0);
    indices.push(j+1);
    var l = j+2;
    if (l == CONE_DIV + 2) { //last vertex base - return to first
      indices.push(2);
    } else {
      indices.push(l);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER's type is in BYTE instead of SHORT?

Comment: Yes, bit with SHORT It doesn't work, nothing is displayed

Comment: If you switch your indcies to `Uint16Array` you also need to change the 3rd parameter of your call to `gl.drawElements` to `gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT`.

Comment: But I use uint8